# Error while building react-native app with expo eas

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

When I'm building my React Native app, on running `gradlew` I get this error. After a successful build, my app should display a main menu with 5 navigation buttons to other views/screens - work on the expo emulator but after building the apk I only show the default splash screen for 5-6 seconds and the app turns off - can someone help?

[Error Page image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO9bh.png)

[Error Page image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkwKM.png)

[Error Page image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lePxo.png)

I updated `expo` and `react-native`, reinstalled all dependencies for the project, and cleared the project cache. Unfortunately, I still get the same error and the apk doesn't work properly. I don't know what other options I can try to make this apk work.